# How did Peter and Agent Lee cross to the other universe using Walter's machine?

Tags: fringe

I am watching *Fringe* and it is really fun but there is something I couldn't understand at all.
In episode 8 of season 4, "Back to Where You've Never Been", Peter and Agent Lee cross to the other universe, using the machine that Walter built, and get Peter.

How did they use it? I thought it was because of the tear between universes and I remember Walter saying once that using it again will destroy the universes.